# Awesomium webBrowser control - How Focus on A TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, webbrowser-control, awesomium

Here is my jquery codes :

```
    webBrowser_main.ExecuteJavascript("$('input[name=\"username\"]').val('only this one');");
    webBrowser_main.ExecuteJavascript("$('input[name=\"username\"]').click();");
    webBrowser_main.ExecuteJavascript("$('input[name=\"username\"]').focus();");
```

The first line works very well, But i can't focus on username TextBox.
How can i do that using with Awesomium.Net control?
For the Regular WebBrowser control the codes below works :

```
    webBrowser_main.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", Username);
    webBrowser_main.Document.GetElementById("username").InvokeMember("click");
    webBrowser_main.Document.GetElementById("username").Focus();
```

How can i right such these codes for Awesomium control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it should work.

```
     var javascript = @"(function (){ 

           //write JavaScript code here.
          document.getElementById('username').value = 'only this one';
          var a = document.getElementById('username');
          var evnt = a['onclick'];

          if (typeof(evnt) == 'function') {
             evnt.call(a);
          }
         document.getElementById('username').focus();

        })()";

         webBrowser_main.ExecuteJavascript(javascript );
```

Comment: welcome. Make sure webpage already has Jquery reference then you can populate function body with jquery as well.

Comment: no, Awesomium.. is not going to work like web browser control.awesome gives you control over html via injecting script this is the only way i know.